# How do I sort a list of string by part of it in Python?

Tags: python, sorting

Here is a list of key from a dictionary:

```
bandlist = ['B28', 'B26', 'B11', 'B21', 'B20', 'B7', 'B13', 'B3', 'B19', 'B8', 'B1']

sorted(bandlist) == ['B1', 'B11', 'B13', 'B19', 'B20', 'B21', 'B26', 'B28', 'B3', 'B7', 'B8']
```

But I want it to be arranged in the order of the number after 'B', such as:

```
['B1', 'B3', 'B7', 'B8', 'B11', 'B13', 'B19', 'B20', 'B21', 'B26', 'B28']
```

How can I do?

Comment: There's also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287209/sort-list-of-strings-by-integer-suffix-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use optional `key` argument:

```
>>> bandlist = ['B28', 'B26', 'B11', 'B21', 'B20', 'B7', 'B13', 'B3', 'B19', 'B8', 'B1']
>>> sorted(bandlist, key=lambda x: int(x[1:]))
['B1', 'B3', 'B7', 'B8', 'B11', 'B13', 'B19', 'B20', 'B21', 'B26', 'B28']
```