# How to sort python list by numbers?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

I would like to sort the following list by numbers :

```
x = ('a-34','a-1','a-0', 'a-11', 'a-2')
y = sorted(x)
print(y)
```

This produces : `['a-0', 'a-1', 'a-11', 'a-2', 'a-34']`

But I need : ['a-0', 'a-1', 'a-2', 'a-11', 'a-34']
How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort list of strings by integer suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287209/sort-list-of-strings-by-integer-suffix)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort list of strings by integer suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287209/sort-list-of-strings-by-integer-suffix)

Comment: Oops; somehow [Sort list of strings by integer suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287209/sort-list-of-strings-by-integer-suffix) didn't make it into the list of duplicates when the question was closed.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `sorted` with the key argument:

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[-1]))
['a-0', 'a-1', 'a-2', 'a-11', 'a-34']
>>>
```

Or indexing with `find`:

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: int(x[x.find('-') + 1:]))
['a-0', 'a-1', 'a-2', 'a-11', 'a-34']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using the `key` parameter in the `sorted()` function

```py
>>> sorted(a, key = lambda x: x.split('-')[-1])
['a-0', 'a-1', 'a-11', 'a-2', 'a-34']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the key argument  in sorted method and provide a lambda function to it.

```
sorted(a, key = lambda x: int(x.split("-")[-1]))
```